# unsupported operand type str and str

Tags: python

I have questions regarding applying functions across columns in data frame for python:
When I tried to apply this remove_outlier_IQR function across all the columns in my dataframe using the delete_outlier_IQR(), there is this unsupported operand error:

```py
def remove_outlier_IQR(feature):
    Q1 = df[feature].quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = df[feature].quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    upbound   = Q3 + 6 * IQR
    downbound = Q1 - 6 * IQR
    num_outlier = len(df[((df[feature] < downbound)|(df[feature] > upbound))][feature])
    percent_outlier = num_outlier / len(df[feature])
 #   print(percent_outlier)
    if(percent_outlier > 0.1):
        index_outlier = list(df[((df[feature] < downbound)|(df[feature] > upbound))][feature].index)
    #    print(index_outlier)
        print('outlier > 10%')
    else: 
        index_outlier = list(df[((df[feature] < downbound)|(df[feature] > upbound))][feature].index)
    #    print(index_outlier)
        print('outlier < 10%')
    
def delete_outlier_IQR():
    for col in df.columns:
        remove_outlier_IQR(col)
        
delete_outlier_IQR()
```

Then this is my error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: What should `"something" - "else"` result it? Or do you have `"2" - "3"`? In that case you need to convert the data to integers such that you can properly subtract them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I have questions regarding" - please read [ask], and **ask a question** - one per post, please. Before asking, try to study and understand the problem, so that you can properly focus on exactly what it is that you want to know. For example, what do you think the error message means? Where in the code do you think the problem is occurring? What do you think is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to do a calculation using Strings. Convert them to integers first and that should solve the issue.

Example:

```
int(to_be_converted_string) - int(other_string)
```